# HttpListener accepts 2 times for each connection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, connection, httplistener

I was testing C# HttpListener with VS2019, console application for .net core 3.1

First, I used powershell under admin mode and ran:

```
> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/ user=everyone
```

Then my C# program as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("...Wait until all async finish");
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(@"http://+:80/");
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wait one connection");
            var context = listener.GetContext();
            var response = context.Response;
            Console.WriteLine("... Got one connection response");
            var responseString = $"<html><body><h1>Hellow,How are You?{DateTime.Now}</h1></body></html>";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            using (var stream = response.OutputStream)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Response done\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, each time I use edge or chrome to browse "localhost", the while loop run 2 times, and print the line "Response done" two times.

I expect that each time I create a new browser tag for "localhost" or refrsh the page, my program should only enter while loop once. So what's the problem like?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The browser makes an additional request to get the favicon.ico of your page.
You can verify the requests which are sent to your HttpListener in the Network tab in the browser:

[image: Example]